# MYSQL QUERY Fetching multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with the query..

```
SELECT av.A,
       ad.* 
FROM ads ad 
     RIGHT JOIN `B` av  
     ON ad.serial =  av.adid
WHERE ad.status='1' 
      AND  EXISTS (SELECT  * 
                   FROM attvalues 
                   WHERE adid =ad.serial 
                         AND (av.atrid = '104'  
                              AND av.atrid = '98'))
```

i want to retrieve which is matches both conditions 104 AND 98. I can use OR  but it will match only 1 condition

You can also give me alternative query if this way is not correct..

Comment: How can `av.atrid` be equal to 104 and 98 at the same time?

Comment: Please explain clearly what you want. If you want to find a record where _one_ field has _two_ different values at the same time, then your query is correct and it will _never_ return _anything_, since av.atrid can _never_ have two different values at any time. So please, explain better what you are tryign to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to retrieve records for which BOTH a record with atrid 104 and a record with atrid 98 exist. In that case you want all your records which have 98 OR 104, and there have to be exactly 2, so I suggest a group by and a count(*). Note that I am assuming also that your atrid is in attvalues, as I cannot think of any way to otherwise make your WHERE statement work, you cannot select fro attvalues where some value in `B` has any value...

```
SELECT av.A,
       ad.* 
FROM ads ad 
     RIGHT JOIN `B` av  
     ON ad.serial =  av.adid
WHERE ad.status='1' 
      AND  EXISTS (SELECT  X.adid
                     FROM attvalues X
                    WHERE X.adid =ad.serial 
                      AND (X.atrid = '104' OR X.atrid = '98')
                     GROUP BY X.adid
                      HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```